# Can build and run on the simulator but cannot archive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7.3, promisekit

I am trying to solve a problem for a week now.

I can successfully build and run my app on the simulator but when I try to upload it to the app store, I cannot archive it.

Can you help with what might be the problem?

I am using the PromiseKit version 3.5.0, Xcode version 7.3.1

[image]

Comment: Please post relevant error messages at text into your question.

Comment: Also note that you really need to be using Xcode 9 and newer versions of Swift. I'm not sure you can even use Xcode 7 any more to submit apps to the App Store.

Comment: Yeah, today although I solved the problem, I got stuck on the app store submission process. Now we can all be sure Xcode 7.3.1 developed apps cannot publish to the App Store :)